# Prefix to Postfix conversion with parentheses

Tags: c++, postfix-notation, prefix-notation

I am really stuck in make conversion of special prefix to postfix operation on our task, let me describe the task similarly :

We have such operation to use as operations in our prefixes, here is the method that i am checking them :

```
bool isOperator(string c)
{
    if (c == "log" || c == "exp" || c == "sum" || c == "div" || c == "abs" || c == "sqrt" || c == "sub" || c == "product" || c == "max" || c== "min" || c == "mod" )     // you may add operator here
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Anyway example prefix instructions can have parentheses to make operation precedence, this is what I am stuck at. I know, I need to implement such a recursion, but i can't find a way.

```
div ( sqrt 5 ) 3
```

Output should be

```
5 sqrt 3 div
```

Another example :

```
div ( sum ( exp 2 3 ) ( sqrt 5 ) ) 3
```

Output

```
2 3 exp 5 sqrt sum 3 div
```

Every operation, parentheses or number should have space between elements in assumed condition.

My stack implementation

Stack.h

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node {
    string op ;
    node *next;
};

struct Stack {
    node * head;
    void create();
    void close();
    void push (node *);
    node* pop();
    node* top();
    bool isEmpty();

};
```

Stack.cpp

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include "stack.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

void Stack::create() {
    head = NULL;
}

void Stack::close() {
    node *p;
    while (head) {
        p = head;
        head = head->next;
        //delete [] p->data;
        delete p;
    }
}

void Stack::push(node *newdata) {
    node *newnode = new node;
    newnode = newdata;
    newnode->op = newdata->op;
    newnode->next = head;
    head = newnode;
}

node *Stack::pop() {
    if (isEmpty())
        return NULL;
    node *topnode = head;
    head = head->next;
    //delete topnode;
    return topnode;
}

node *Stack::top() {
    if (isEmpty())
        return NULL;
    node *topnode = head;
    //delete topnode;
    return topnode;
}
bool Stack::isEmpty() {
    return (head == NULL);
}
```

as @PaulMcKenzie mentioned, i've tried an implementation below, sub_array string array contains the word list without spaces.

```
bool isLeftParanthesis(string c)
{
    if (c == "(" )   // you may add operator here
        return true;
    return false;
}
bool isRightParanthesis(string c)
{
    if (c == ")")    // you may add operator here
        return true;
    return false;
}
int main()
{
string prefix;
getline(cin, prefix);
istringstream iss(prefix);
istringstream iss2(prefix);
int count1 = 0, count2 = 0;
string postfix = "";
Stack *st = new Stack;
string t1, t2;

string sub;
string *sub_array;
while (iss >> sub) {
    count1++;
}
sub_array = new string[count1];
while (iss2 >> sub) {
    sub_array[count2] = sub;
    count2++;
}
int l = count1;

int right_p_count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < count1; i++)
{
    if (isRightParanthesis(sub_array[i]))
    {
        right_p_count++;
    }
}
string *postfixes = new string[right_p_count];
int index_right_p = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < count1; i++) {
    while (!isRightParanthesis(sub_array[i]))
    {
        node *n = new node;
        n->op = sub_array[i];
        st->push(n);
        i++;
        if (i == count1)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    if( i != count1){
    if (isRightParanthesis(sub_array[i])) {
        postfix = "";
        while (!isLeftParanthesis(st->top()->op))
        {
            string t = st->pop();
            if (!isOperator(t) && !isLeftParanthesis(t) && !isRightParanthesis(t)) {
                postfix = t + " " + postfix;
            }
            else if (isOperator(t)) {
                postfix = postfix + " " + t;
            }
        }
        st->pop();
        postfixes[index_right_p] = postfix;
        index_right_p++;
    }
    }
    postfix = "";
    while ( !st->isEmpty() && index_right_p == right_p_count && i == count1)
    {
        string t = st->pop();
        if (!isOperator(t) && !isLeftParanthesis(t) && !isRightParanthesis(t)) {
            postfix = t+" "+postfix;
        }
        else if (isOperator(t)) {
            postfix = postfix+""+t;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
}

string result = "";
for (int i = 0; i < right_p_count; i++)
{
    result = result + "" + postfixes[i];
}
result = result + " " + postfix;
cout << result << endl;
}
```

Variable postfix refers to output postfix, but my output is not wrong for some of the operations such as :

```
div ( sqrt 5 ) 3
```

When i saw a parantheses i am checking if it is left or right, using right one for trigger.

```
abs ( product -2 -4 -8 )
```

Expected output is :

```
-2 -4 -8 product abs
```

UPDATE : I solved stack problem myself, but found out that, algorithm calculates some expressions wrongly...

Example expression :

```
3 2 3 exp sum
```

Expected output :

```
sum 3 ( exp 2 3 )
```

My output :

```
2 3 exp 3 sum
```

My algorithm which is using right parentheses as triggers calculates it wrongly and I don't know how to implement this control into that, are there any suggestions ?

Comment: How will `isParenthesis` distinguish between left and right paren?  It is the left paren that is always pushed, and the right paren is the trigger to pop everything until the corresponding left paren is encountered.  That's how it's done for infix to postfix, and I assume this is no different for prefix to postfix.

Comment: There are no parentheses in either prefix or postfix notation. There is something seriously wrong with your assignment.

Comment: @EJP I also think like you but as i've mentioned this is specific implementation of prefix that we have to adapt into...

Comment: @Hayra Why? Unless the functions don't know how many arguments they are expecting, the parentheses are redundant. They certainly do *not* express anything in relation to precedence, which is already built-in to both prefix and postfix notations.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i've implemented a solution with sugesstion of yours, but it seems that there are bugs still...